# RewriteRule for redirecting lots of similar 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a bombardment of 404 requests for files that never have been there.

Like
https://www.livingtale.nl/aXRlZG9oby8xNDAzMC9TV0VFVC80OTIv

all begin with
aXRIZG9oby8

I would like to redirect them to
https://www.livingtale.nl/escaperoom.html

What should be the RewriteRule?

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^aXRlZG9oby8(.*)$    /escaperoom.html [L,R=301]
```

But i noticed that you any page to handle error pages at your site and for better practice , no mention the above case , it is better to create custom 404 page all wrong request to keep visitors aware that the page they're looking for is not found and you can add some info to guide them as well.

So you could add this to handle all wrong request :

```
ErrorDocument 404     /path/to/error/page
```

Right now , the request that starts with `aXRlZG9oby8` will be treated by the first rule and others wrong requests will be treated by the second and if you want to keep the second one for all , just remove the first rules

Comment: Thank you very much. It's a great relieve. And thank you as well for your reflection on the 404 page. I had the pages alright but at some moment the ErrordDocument rule was lost!

Comment: glad to help , Thanks